# how tcp stack deal with the ack_seq number and seq number of tcp FIN/ACK packet?

Tags: networking, tcp, tcpip

from my knowledge, seq and ack_seq are processed by tcp stack independently.

when a packet arrives with a inconsistent ack_seq number

if: 1) the ack_seq number is obsolete(smaller than expected), e.g, a dup ACK, this packet doesn't fail the validity check, so if it has data field, and the seq number is correct, the data is still accepted due to the independence of seq and ack_seq processing.

2) if the ack_seq number is ahead (larger than expected), then it fails validity check, this packet will not be delivered to tcp stack. So even if the processing between seq and ack_seq is independent, there is a invalidity issue before the processing. And the packet will not be processed by TCP stack.

[image: pcap file]

http://postimg.org/image/82cyf2cw9/

( Note: there are some sequence number inconsistency in the tcp connection between 138.96.116.9 and 138.96.201.72, I'm not going to talk about the inconsistency problem, it is another topic)

However, from the graph above, in the 1013-th packet, 138.96.201.72 sends a FIN/ACK packet, it has an ack_seq 2086 which is ahead of the sequence number(1) of the 1011-th packet. In theory, the FIN/ACK fails the validity check and should not be accepted/processed by the tcp stack. But the host 138.96.116.9 sends back a tcp ACK(the 1014-th packet). Why?

And besides, although the 1014-th ACK packet has wrong seq number(which is 2, but expected to be 2086), it has a correct ack_seq number and doesn't fail the validity check. And according to the principle of independent processing, it acknowledged the 1013-th FIN/ACK packet correctly. Why 138.96.201.72 still retransmit the FIN/ACK?

Comment: Can you add an image when the connection was established, i.e. the syn/syn-ack/ack sequence?

Comment: I was doing some experiments about ip/spoofingtcp hijacking, so at the very begining, I have a third program disturbing the sequence number. Anyway, packets exchange in this picture are between 2 normal tcp program. And I'm just interested on how normal tcp stack react to inconsistent sequence number.